# Google sheets: Can I combine offset over range, based on dropdown?

Tags: google-sheets, offset

I'm trying to build a yearplan for speedskating. Blah blah blah, context, what matters is that I can't work this bit out. I want "week type" to be filled with 1 to 10 cells, based on input from the "Cycle type". If I choose, for example, 6 wk, I want 6 cells (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and then be able to pick 3 wk below. I'm not sure how to do this, but I've come quite far already.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EZ61f24t3SYAMkuTof6PjkcBNxSkVVdC5AJpxMoQrnM/edit?usp=sharing

This is the link to the sheet. [This is the end result I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSw2H.png)

I'd appreciate some help, I've been stuck at this for quite some time! :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to get "Cycle type" filled automatically according to "week type" form the input table like this.

[image]

In order to do that we need:
1 - Data validation in column 01 of output table from the input table "Cyclus type" we go Data > data validation - Criteria: list from range and select the range `D3:D`

[image: Input table]

2 - we need to normalize the input table, paste this `QUERY` fuction formula in `Q3`.

```
=QUERY({C3:D,F3:F;C3:D,G3:G;C3:D,H3:H;C3:D,I3:I;C3:D,J3:J;C3:D,K3:K;C3:D,L3:L;C3:D,M3:M;C3:D,N3:N;C3:D,O3:O}, " Select * Where Col1 is not null ")
```

Note that `QUERY` with Arrays `{}` in english local `,` to join columns side by side and `;` to stack them, in Dutch however `\` replaces `,` and `;` is the same.

[image: Normalized table]

3 - we need a helper table by pasting this formula in `W3` and drag down.

```
=IF(U3="",,TRANSPOSE(FILTER($S$3:$S,$R$3:$R=U3)))
```

[image: Healper table]

Note: it can be hidden or collapsed using goups.

4 - Paste this formula to get all the results stacked under "Cyclus type"

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN(W3:AF),FLATTEN(W3:AF)<>"")
```

[image: Output Table]

I hope that answres you question.

Comment: Oh man, that definitely helps! I don't know enough about Google Sheets to see what you're doing exactly, but now that I have your answer I'll read up on the formula's and the use of data validation as well. 
You've been a great help!! Thanks :)